# How to run a hana shared procedure from java

Tags: java, procedure, hana

The below procedure is running fine in hana studio

```
call "ABC"."defg.shared.procedures::SOME_XYZ_WRAPPER"
```

I'm trying to call this from java code as follow

```
queryStr = call "ABC"."defg.shared.procedures::SOME_XYZ_WRAPPER";
CallableStatement ca = conn.prepareCall("{"+queryStr+"}");
ca.execute();
```

but I'm getting a syntax error.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You want to include the whole `call` statement into your `queryStr` and escape the included quotation marks:

```
queryStr = "call \"ABC\".\"defg.shared.procedures::SOME_XYZ_WRAPPER\"";
```

Why don't you check the reference documentation [Calling SQLScript from Java](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.03/en-US/5cde27dd6d2a411294645a8d1e8321d7.html) to see a working example code?